# Is it possible to change where things are in Chrome's Developer Tools Script panel?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome

When debugging browser-based apps using Google Chrome's Developer Tools, is there a way to change the locations of the various panes? Specifically in the Scripts panel (though I suppose it's a general question). E.g., the Watch Expressions, the Call Stack, the code pane, etc.?

The defaults are okay (console at bottom, code pane upper left, a column of Watch Expressions, Call Stack, Scope Vars, etc. in the upper right), but I'd rather swap things around a bit if it's possible.

There doesn't seem to be anything to grab (other than for sizing) and I haven't found a way in my searching so far, but there are (still) some things about Chrome's options that aren't ... *well-advertised* in the UI, shall we say :-), especially around developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  If you raise a bug on [http://crbug.com] you can track the status of it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a specific reference for that (that it's not possible), or just speaking from personal experience like mine?

Comment: And: I was waiting to file the enh. req. until at least *one* other person confirmed that they didn't think there was a way. So I've filed it now: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40913

Comment: Someone from chromium.org has updated the issue to flag it with the type (feature request), priority (2), area (UI), and feature (DevTools), rather than closing it as "already implemented" or something. So I'm thinking this is the right answer. :-)